# n highest values of a list in Python

Tags: python, sorting

What is the best way to get the n highest values of a given list? If we are in a case where n is rather small compared to the length of `alist`, is there something more efficient than:

```
alist.sort()
return alist[0:n]
```

Comment: You got the `n` *lowest* values instead there. You probably want `l[-n:]`.

Comment: This is probably the most concise, but not the most efficient.  What's your definition of "best"?

Comment: It's not the most concise: `sorted(l)[-n:]`

Comment: @larsmans Fair enough, though that is perilously close to being pedantic...

Comment: Yes of course, it was -n, sorry. But the question was more about using a sorting algorithm that stops when it has found the n higest (or lowest) values instead of sorting the whole list

Comment: @interjay: Indeed. Voting to reopen to then close as a dupe of that target instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`heapq` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html):

```
import heapq

return heapq.nlargest(n, l)
```

Using a heap queue is more efficient than a full sort provided you are looking for a relatively smaller number of `n` elements. If `n` is larger, `sorted(l)[-n:]` is more efficient. The `heapq.nlargest()` implementation does test for these conditions and will switch to using `sorted()` if it can determine `n` is equal to or larger than `len(l)`.

Note that the `heapq` module will modify the list in-place (`heapq.heapify()` is called on the list).

Answer (score 0):

Your method is very concise, but it may not be the most efficient. One possibility would be to implement a deterministic selection algorithm (As is explained [here in text](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960130.html) and [here in video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XEh_jiob7lM)), then call that for the values you want. That would give you and O(n) operation overall, and since you're talking about going through a list I don't think you'll be able to get *significantly* better.